# when does L1 distance give similar performance as L2 distance in KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

Here is the tricky question:

Say in a KNN we have used L2 distance (Euclidean distance). We can also use other distance metrics such as L1 distance. The performance of a Nearest Neighbor classifier that uses L1 distance will not change if:

1. The data is preprocessed by subtracting the mean.
2. The data is preprocessed by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.
3. The coordinate axes for the data are rotated.
4. None of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only 2 is true because the others change the L1 distance too much

Answer (score 0):

1, 2 and 3 are all right.

1 is the translation, 3 is the rotation. Both of them do not change the L1 distance. So the KNN result does not change.

2 is translation + scale. Although L1 is changed, the relative locations of points are still the same. So the KNN result is the same with before.